# Replace specific values in all rows corresponding to each ID

Tags: r

I have a data set with multiple rows per ID and a column with an indicator that varies from row to row.

```
ID  V1
1   A
1   C
1   B
2   B
2   A
2   A
3   B
3   C
3   C
```

I would like **all** rows of `V1` to be replaced with `A` for every ID, only if there is at least one entry in `V1` that equals to `A` for each ID, otherwise keep as is. The output I am looking for is as follows:

```
ID  V1
1   A
1   A
1   A
2   A
2   A
2   A
3   B
3   C
3   C
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is V1 numeric, or is it factors?

Comment: V1 is a string/character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest solution I have at the moment involves creating an intermediate column and then dropping it (I will see if I can instead fit this into a one-liner):

```
# group by ID and if "A" is present in any rows in group
# assign "A"; otherwise assign NA  
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(V2 = ifelse(any(V1 == "A"), "A", NA))
# overwrite "V1" with "A" if value in column "V2" is "A"
df$V1[which(df$V2 == "A")] <- "A"
# drop temporary column
df$V2 <- NULL
```

Edit: here is the one-liner, courtesy of @thelatemail.

```
dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(V1=if(any(V1=="A")) "A" else V1)
```

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(V1=if(any(V1=="A")) "A" else V1)` to do it all in one go

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm! It is amazing what dplyr can do sometimes.

Comment: @thelatemail thank you, good call -- when I tried that approach with `ifelse` it didn't get the assignment right (it would return "B" for all rows of group 3). I think the difference is that the function `ifelse`, in this case, was still seeing the grouped values. I will make the change.

Comment: @DenysD. you're welcome -- see the revised answer too for the one-line solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can do with `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'ID', `if` there is 'A' `%in%` `V1`, assign (`:=` 'A' to 'V1' or `else` return 'V1'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, V1 := if('A' %in% V1) 'A' else V1, ID]
df
#    ID V1
#1:  1  A
#2:  1  A
#3:  1  A
#4:  2  A
#5:  2  A
#6:  2  A
#7:  3  B
#8:  3  C
#9:  3  C
```

---

Or we can use a `base R` solution with `ave`

```
df$V1[with(df, ave(V1=="A", ID, FUN = any))] <- 'A'
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V1 = c("A", 
"C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C")), .Names = c("ID", "V1"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```